# Customers not able to login intermittently

Tags: cookie, ee-1.13, ee-1.13.1.0

I am using Magento 1.13.1.0, and getting this issue appearing differently on different browsers.

- On **Chrome**, customers are not able to logged in at all.
- On **Opera**, Customers are able to logged in but redirecting to home page and to links are not updating (from Login to My Account )
- On **Firefox** the issue is not coming, customers are able to login and redirect properly on my account pages.

If anyone has any suggestion on this issue please share.

Comment: Can you please check for the coookies and session settings in magento admin?please go to admin -> system -> configuration -> web -> session cookies management and session validation settings.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. I already did this but wont work for me unfortunately..